# How to increase number of reducer in canopy clustering algorithm

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mahout, canopy

I'm running canopy clustering algorithm using mahout.

This is the command I'm running through mahout Command line.

```
mahout canopy -i /mahout/o_seqsparse/tfidf-vectors -o /mahout/o_canopy -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.SquaredEuclideanDistanceMeasure -ow -t1 100 -t2 50
```

Below is number of map & reduce task running:

No. of map tasks runing --> 6

No. of reduce tasks runing --> **1**

But this is taking too much time because of one reducer. I think, if I am able to increase the number of reduce tasks, then I will get better performance.

I also tried with increasing  map reduce with `mapred-site.xml` file **mapred.map.tasks,** **mapred.reduce.tasks**
But this has no effect, still it is running with 1 reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt specify the version of mahout you are using. But looking at the source code of 0.4 here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.4/org/apache/mahout/clustering/canopy/CanopyDriver.java

You can find 1 reducer is hard coded. I dont think you can override it.

### EDIT

For version 0.9 as you specified check here http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.9/org/apache/mahout/clustering/canopy/CanopyDriver.java/ at line no. 354

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```

Modify this and build again. However the map output **must be sent to one reducer.** **In case of clustering I dont believe you will benefit much by increasing the number of reducers.**

Comment: I'm using mahout 0.9 (i.e hdp2)

Comment: That's a correct answer, but a wrong suggestion. The point is that a single reducer SHOULD be used, in order to compare all the canopy centers. Bad algorithm I would dare to say, but this is the way to run it.

Comment: Exactly why I specified "However in case of clustering I dont believe you will benefit much by increasing the number of reducers." I think I should put it in bold!

Comment: +1 for the explanation. "Modify this and build again." however, should be removed IMHO, as it would give wrong results as you suggest in the bold sentence. It's not that it would not benefit much, but it would give wrong results.

Comment: Thank you Abhiroop, As you say , if I increase number of reducer then it will give wrong result. currently I'm running canopy clustering on 3 lac documents, in this case performance is very poor. what should I do.

Answer (score 2):

As Abhiroop Sarkar mentions in his answer, using a single reducer is hard coded. However, it is not simply a matter of how much you benefit by using one or more reducers. You should **not** use more than one reducers, otherwise the algorithm would not run correctly.  The reason is that by using a single reducer at this step, all the canopy centers will be compared to each other, making sure that they are not "too close" to each other.

So, what you correctly specified as the bottleneck of this algorithm, cannot be changed. In fact, if you have too many canopy centers, it will also run out of memory. Not an ideal transformation of the original sequential algorithm IMHO, since it cannot fully exploit parallel programming, but its the only one available (and/or possible) in MapReduce.

In a nutshell, a single reducer is used to return canopy centers away from each other. **Using more reducers would give wrong results.**

Comment: It is not a bad transformation, it is just two iterations of a canopy clustering. There is no other way to express it in MapReduce.

Comment: Okay, I agree on that. I was myself trying to figure out a parallel version of this algorithm, too, but couldn't find an exact solution. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you vefthym. Is there other way to do canapy clustering.

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde Unfortunately, there is no other way to do that in MapReduce, but there is also the original sequential algorithm. Weka has an implementation of that: weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/Canopy.html